# Variables of the same type are not equal to each other

Tags: javascript, variables

Why should `dropdowns[i]` be assigned to the variable `openDropdown` in here? However the `console.log()` for both `dropdowns[i]` and `openDropdown` is equal.

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If they are equal, why this code doesn't work?

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            if (dropdowns[i].classList.contains('show')) {
                dropdowns[i].classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you do `var a = b`, and then log `a` and `b`, of course they will be the same.

Comment: Are you sure that code does not work? Can you create a minimal example that can be executed here?

Comment: Both examples are functional identical. In the latter, someone just wanted to avoid the bracket notation. No magic here really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line :

```
var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
```

Is giving one more name (`openDropdown`) to the existing value `dropdowns[i]`.

It is not creating a copy of the value of `dropdowns[i]`. So when modifying openDropdown afterward, you are touching the value that you can reach through the names `openDropdowns` and `dropdowns[i]`.

Depending on your needs, you may have to search for shallow or deep copies of javascript objects.